# Android custom Row Item for ListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView that should have the following layout in its rows:

```
HEADER
Text
```

`HEADER` should be static but the `Text` changes every few seconds.

I implemented it by populating a `String[] array`, pass it to an `ArrayAdapter` and set it every time the data changes:

```
data_array = populateString();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,  data_array);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My problem is that I do not know how to display the data in the format above.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590627/android-listview-headers

Comment: create a custom adapter and override the getView() method to meet your need

Comment: you have to use baseadapter with xml layout for rows in your list view

Comment: you have to create a custom layout.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

#### Add this row.xml to your layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Header"/>

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text"/>
    
    
</LinearLayout>
```

#### make your main xml layout as this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is your adapter

```
class yourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    String[] data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public yourAdapter(Context context, String[] data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(data[position]);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

#### Your java activity

```
public class StackActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listview;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listview.setAdapter(new yourAdapter(this, new String[] { "data1",
                "data2" }));
    }
}
```

#### the results

[image]

Comment: when working with a fragment what should be the argument in place of context which is first argument to yourAdapter constructor method 'listview.setAdapter(new yourAdapter(this, new String[] { "data1",
                "data2" }));'

Comment: Sorry that late, but I get null when I try to use .setText. Do you have any idea of what can it be?

Comment: @Novalink that means the `TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);` is null, are you sure that the `R.id.text` is there?

Comment: my row.xml looks exactly like that, just there is a text1 and text2.

Comment: @Novalink post a new question and send me the link please

Answer (score 9):

Use a custom Listview.

You can also customize how row looks by having a custom background.
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:background="#0095FF"> //background color

<ListView android:id="@+id/list"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="0dip"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
 android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
 android:layout_weight="2"
 android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
 android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
 android:dividerHeight="8dp" 
 android:divider="#000000" 
 android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
</ListView>
```

MainActivity

Define populateString() in MainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   String data_array[];
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            data_array = populateString(); 
    ListView ll = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    CustomAdapter cus = new CustomAdapter();
    ll.setAdapter(cus);
}

class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    LayoutInflater mInflater;


    public CustomAdapter()
    {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data_array.length;//listview item count. 
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position; 
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder vh;
        vh= new ViewHolder();

        if(convertView==null )
         {
            convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent,false);
                    //inflate custom layour
            vh.tv2= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

         }
        else
        {
         convertView.setTag(vh);
        }
               //vh.tv2.setText("Position = "+position);
            vh.tv2.setText(data_array[position]);   
                           //set text of second textview based on position

        return convertView;
    }

 class ViewHolder
 {
    TextView tv1,tv2;
 }

   }  
}
```

row.xml. Custom layout for each row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Header" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Inflate a custom layout. Use a **view holder for smooth scrolling** and performance.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70. The talk is about listview performance by android developers.

[image]

Comment: OnCreate after ll.SetAdapter(cus) application suddenly stops working

Comment: is it a crash?. if so crash log should help you fix the same

Comment: Sorry, It was my fault. I am using AndroidAnnotations and the problem was I didn't use the correct R.layout.{layout_id}. Your code works fine.

Answer (score 5):

create resource layout file list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_text"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Header"
        />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="dynamic text"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

and initialise adaptor like this

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,R.id.item_text,data_array);
```

Comment: This is the simplest method I've found and it worked for me at first try. Target Api Level 16.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:Create a XML File**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvItems"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Step 2:Studnet.java**

```
package com.scancode.acutesoft.telephonymanagerapp;


public class Student
{
    String email,phone,address;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

**Step 3:MainActivity.java**

```
 package com.scancode.acutesoft.telephonymanagerapp;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

        ListView lvItems;
        ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList ;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
            studentArrayList = new ArrayList<Student>();
            dataSaving();
            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,studentArrayList);
            lvItems.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        private void dataSaving() {

            Student student = new Student();
            student.setEmail("abc@gmail.com");
            student.setPhone("1234567890");
            student.setAddress("Hyderabad");
            studentArrayList.add(student);


            student = new Student();
            student.setEmail("xyz@gmail.com");
            student.setPhone("1234567890");
            student.setAddress("Banglore");
            studentArrayList.add(student);

            student = new Student();
            student.setEmail("xyz@gmail.com");
            student.setPhone("1234567890");
            student.setAddress("Banglore");
            studentArrayList.add(student);

            student = new Student();
            student.setEmail("xyz@gmail.com");
            student.setPhone("1234567890");
            student.setAddress("Banglore");
            studentArrayList.add(student);
        }


    }
```

**Step 4:CustomAdapter.java**

```
  package com.scancode.acutesoft.telephonymanagerapp;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        ArrayList<Student> studentList;
        Context mContext;


        public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList) {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.studentList = studentArrayList;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return studentList.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            Student student = studentList.get(position);
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.student_row,null);

            TextView tvStudEmail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvStudEmail);
            TextView tvStudPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvStudPhone);
            TextView tvStudAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvStudAddress);

            tvStudEmail.setText(student.getEmail());
            tvStudPhone.setText(student.getPhone());
            tvStudAddress.setText(student.getAddress());


            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get "variable studentList might not have been initialized". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you can follow `BaseAdapter` and create your custome `Xml` file and bind it with you `BaseAdpter` and populate it with `Listview` [see here](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/)  need to change `xml` file as Require.