# Confused on what kind of listView and adapter to use in Android for a small array

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I haven't worked with listViews much, and now I need help on deciding what kind of adapter to use.

I have three headers that I need:

```
String fruit = "Fruits";
String vegetable = "Vegetables";
String bread = "Breads"
```

I also have three array that I want to use as the data of the listView(not using a database for this sample app). I might want to have three ArrayLists instead, but for now I'll be using arrays.

```
String[] fruits = {"Apple","Orange"};
String[] vegetables = {"Potato","Carrot"};
String[] breads = {"Rye","Wheat"};
```

I would like the ListView to look like the Android 4.x settings screen with a "header" title.

```
Fruits
___________________________
Apple
---------------------------
Orange
---------------------------
Vegetables
___________________________
Potato
---------------------------
Carrot
---------------------------
Breads
___________________________
Rye
---------------------------
Wheat
---------------------------
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for something like this? Again... I may want to switch over to ArrayList if that allows me to add a fruit during run time.

Answer (score 0):

There is an android library available for this and it may solve your issue.
https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/

Comment: Is there anything like this on github? I'm not sure how to download this library through code.google.com

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use custom array adapter. Basically, you need to wrap all data for **one row** in a **model** class. And make an array adapter with array of that **model** class as data source.

Check this link, at custom adapter part for reference: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_custom

Answer (score 0):

There is a [native support](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) for creating settings in Android. It will look, just like user application settings activity.

Or if want your own implementation. You should mange this with [model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). Create some class that will wrap those 3 arrays, and he will return the active array base on its states.

Comment: Hmm... I know it's fairly easy to get a settings screen for Android using SharedPreferences, but I'm trying to put this listView together with three different arrays.

Comment: @EGHDK You should use, MVC for that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to use a separate listView for each group. But when you want to have all of them on one list I think you should use [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) and read about 2 methods:     [getViewTypeCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) = 2 in your case and [getItemViewType(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29). The main problem is that you have to calculate what type is on which position:

1. Fruits
2. Apple
3. Orange
4. Vegetables
5. Potato
6. Carrot
7. ...

Answer (score 0):

Use custom adapter. Here is the example.
[Android custom Row Item for ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832335/android-custom-row-item-for-listview)

In addition,

1. create `head.xml` and `body.xml`
2. Do something in

   ```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       View vi = convertView;
       if (vi == null) {
           if ( isHead() ) // check whether the view is head?
               vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.head, null);
           else
               vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.body, null);
       }
       TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
       text.setText(data[position]);
       return vi;
   }
   ```