# How to create an custom View for ListView?

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android-canvas

How to create an custom ListView? I have Adapter, but I don't understand how to create an View like ListView of the Facebook, or App for SMS native from device... I'm needing background for TextView, this background, will have an arrow pointing left or right, I tried to create a View using canvas, but it is very difficult...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15832564/1694387 <- this answer should be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every line in the listView of a layout which can be as complex as you want.Just you need an extra xml file for managing you **custom layout** (it should be contains widgets,fields,images etc as your design ) and the adapter would inflate this layout file for each row in its `getView ()` method and assign the data to the individual views in the row .