# How to draw object values into a listview in android

Tags: android, listview, object, fragment, dynamically-generated

How do I draw the values from objects that I construct with a dialog and put them into a listview.

For instance; I have an object called

```
digitalControlObject(int, int, bool, bool).
```

Now when the user constructs these objects via a dialog box with corresponding input UI to (int, int, bool, bool)

I want to take those objects and add them to a listview - which will then fill in four rows for that object with the corresponding (int, int, bool, bool)

For instance
Row one would be like this:

```
Table Row |Pin Number |Pin Type |Pin Status |Pin Mode
------------------------------------------------------
Row 1     | 13        | 0       | ON        | ON
```

So; for instance, whenever I hit a button that is next to the listview; the dialog box will appear and allow for me to construct another digitalControlObject... then when I submit that dialog box it should append another row in alignment with that data set.

**EDIT:**

So I tried this as code:

```
    package com.example.ioiocontroller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class digitalFragment extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<digitalControlObject> digitalList;
    ListView digitalListView;
    View digitalFragmentView;
    ArrayAdapter listAdapter;
    Button addDigital;
    Button removeDigital;
    public digitalFragment() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater viewInflation, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle SavedInstantState) {



        digitalFragmentView = viewInflation.inflate(
                R.layout.digitalfragment_page, container, false);

        addDigital = (Button) digitalFragmentView
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalAddition);
        removeDigital = (Button) digitalFragmentView
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalRemoval);
        digitalListView = (ListView) digitalFragmentView
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalListView);

        // ADDITION CLICK METHOD FOR DIGITAL IO
        addDigital.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.digitallistview_layout);
                    digitalListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    digitalList.add(new digitalControlObject(0, true, true, 0));


                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                // create and pass the digitalControlObject to the main activity

            }
        });

        // REMOVAL CLICK METHOD FOR DIGITAL IO
        removeDigital.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        return digitalFragmentView;
    }

    public ListView getDigitalListView() {
        return digitalListView;
    }

    public void setDigitalListView(ListView digitalListView) {
        this.digitalListView = digitalListView;
    }

    public View getDigitalFragmentView() {
        return digitalFragmentView;
    }

    public void setDigitalFragmentView(View digitalFragmentView) {
        this.digitalFragmentView = digitalFragmentView;
    }

}
```

However when I compile and run and hit the button for the onclick view I get a nullpointer error?

**EDIT 2:**

Even with those changes it doesn't work; here's my most recent code ... I still get a nullpointer

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater viewInflation, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle SavedInstantState) {

        digitalFragmentView = viewInflation.inflate(
                R.layout.digitalfragment_page, container, false);

        addDigital = (Button) digitalFragmentView
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalAddition);
        removeDigital = (Button) digitalFragmentView
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalRemoval);
        digitalListView = (ListView) digitalFragmentView
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalListView);
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.digitalListView);
        digitalListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // ADDITION CLICK METHOD FOR DIGITAL IO
        addDigital.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                digitalList.add(new digitalControlObject(0, true, true, 0));

                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                // create and pass the digitalControlObject to the main activity

            }
        });

        // REMOVAL CLICK METHOD FOR DIGITAL IO
        removeDigital.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        return digitalFragmentView;
    }
```

[image: Layout screenshot]

**EDIT 3:**

With this latest code I get an instantaneous crash

```
    package com.example.ioiocontroller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class digitalFragment extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<String> digitalList;
    ListView digitalListView;
    View digitalFragmentView;
    Button addDigital;
    Button removeDigital;

    public digitalFragment() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater viewInflation, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle SavedInstantState) {

        digitalFragmentView = viewInflation.inflate(
                R.layout.digitalfragment_page, container, false);

        addDigital = (Button) digitalFragmentView
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalAddition);
        removeDigital = (Button) digitalFragmentView
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalRemoval);
        digitalListView = (ListView) digitalFragmentView
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalListView);
        final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.title, digitalList);
        digitalListView.setAdapter(adapter);;

        // ADDITION CLICK METHOD FOR DIGITAL IO
        addDigital.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                digitalList.add("TEST");

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                // create and pass the digitalControlObject to the main activity

            }
        });

        // REMOVAL CLICK METHOD FOR DIGITAL IO
        removeDigital.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        return digitalFragmentView;
    }

    public ListView getDigitalListView() {
        return digitalListView;
    }

    public void setDigitalListView(ListView digitalListView) {
        this.digitalListView = digitalListView;
    }

    public View getDigitalFragmentView() {
        return digitalFragmentView;
    }

    public void setDigitalFragmentView(View digitalFragmentView) {
        this.digitalFragmentView = digitalFragmentView;
    }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private Context context;

        public MyAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.context = context;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);
            }

            String item = getItem(position);
            if (item!= null) {
                TextView itemView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                if (itemView != null) {
                    itemView.setText("Item: " + item + " in position " + position);
                }
             }

            return view;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
02-27 12:58:10.173: E/Trace(9958): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-27 12:58:10.173: D/jdwp(9958): sendBufferedRequest : len=0x4B
02-27 12:58:10.190: D/dalvikvm(9958): open_cached_dex_file : /data/app/com.example.ioiocontroller-1.apk /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.example.ioiocontroller-1.apk@classes.dex
02-27 12:58:10.193: D/ActivityThread(9958): BIND_APPLICATION handled : 0 / AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{417cecb8 com.example.ioiocontroller}}
02-27 12:58:10.262: D/dalvikvm(9958): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 54K, 11% free 6279K/7027K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
02-27 12:58:10.268: I/dalvikvm-heap(9958): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.678MB for 1536016-byte allocation
02-27 12:58:10.289: D/dalvikvm(9958): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 10% free 7778K/8567K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
02-27 12:58:10.310: D/dalvikvm(9958): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 10% free 7778K/8567K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 21ms
02-27 12:58:10.337: D/ActivityThread(9958): ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{417d02e0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@417cfaa8 {com.example.ioiocontroller/com.example.ioiocontroller.MainActivity}}
02-27 12:58:10.344: D/ActivityThread(9958): ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{417d02e0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@417cfaa8 {com.example.ioiocontroller/com.example.ioiocontroller.MainActivity}}
02-27 12:58:10.365: D/AbsListView(9958): checkAbsListViewlLogProperty get invalid command
02-27 12:58:10.366: D/AndroidRuntime(9958): Shutting down VM
02-27 12:58:10.366: W/dalvikvm(9958): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x411b7908)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:466)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at com.example.ioiocontroller.digitalFragment.onCreateView(digitalFragment.java:41)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15264)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4918)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15264)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15264)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4918)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2163)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15264)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2131)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1242)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1435)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1127)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4650)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:747)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:567)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:536)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:733)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
02-27 12:58:10.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9958):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your dialog has 4 fields?? And you want to add values from field into list view? Is that the only thing?

Comment: Yes; from my object that is constructed by the four fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a `ListView` with a custom row layout with four `TextViews` where you can put the data. Some examples [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832335/android-custom-row-item-for-listview). On this way you can create something like this:

[image]

Then you just have to keep adding data to your `ListAdapter` to add new rows to the `ListView`

---

Responding to your edited answer, without `Logcat` is a guess, I think the problem is here:

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.digitallistview_layout);
```

The best way to test this is creating a simple adapter with a `row_layout.xml` for each row in the `ListView`:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);
        }

        String item = getItem(position);
        if (item!= null) {
            TextView itemView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            if (itemView != null) {
                itemView.setText("Item: " + item + " in position " + position);
            }
         }

        return view;
    }
}
```

This will be your xml `item_row.xml` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/title"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

So to use this:

```
digitalList.add(new digitalControlObject(0, true, true, 0));

MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.title, digitalList);
digitalListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And this `digitalList` has to be inside your `digitalfragment_page` layout because is the one you are inflating in your `Fragment`

Comment: Do I need to specify a width and length of that custom layout? Like, if I make it any size will it resize it automatically?

Comment: Yes, It is like any other layout in Android, you have to specify `layout_height` and `layout_width`. Here http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/ is a very simple example, you just have to create a custom layout with 4 `TextView`, pass the data to your custom `ListAdapter` and show it into the `ListView`.

Comment: can you check out what could be wrong with that implementation?

Comment: Basically I wanted to just add a tester row to see if it would even load the view.

Comment: that didn't seem to work still getting the null pointer for some reason.

Comment: Added some images too :)

Comment: Try with the Adapter in my edited answer! That should work! If it doesn't post logcat with error

Comment: When I put this code in, digitalList is still of type ArrayList<digitalControlObject>, should I change that to string?

Comment: Forgot about that, if you want to test create an `ArrayList` with some `Strings` or you can now modify the adapter to read your object instead of a `String` object (you will have to do that later anyway)

Comment: I added the logcat file and the info with regard to what I had implemented.

Comment: You never initialize `digitalList`. digitalList = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: No problem, we all make mistakes ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a layout with textviews required along with layout with listview. And for the updating of the list automatically, you should give `onclicklistener` to come to same page using `intent`

```
 public class showList extends Activity{

            @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.showlist);
            ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                int field1 = //value from dialog
                int field2 = //value from dialog
                boolean flag1 = //value from dialog
                boolean flag2 = //value from dialog
                hashMap.put("FIELD1", field1+"" );
                hashMap.put("FIELD2", field2+"" );
                hashMap.put("FLAG1", flag1+"" );
                hashMap.put("FLAG2", flag2+"" );
                arrayList.add(hashMap);
            ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(showList.this, arrayList, R.layout.mylayout, new String[]{"FIELD1","FIELD2","FLAG1","FLAG2"},new int[]{R.id.textviewforfield1,R.id.textviewforfield2,R.id.textviewforflag1,R.id.textviewforflag2} );
            myListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't I have to convert the fields into strings first?

Comment: I am not compiling the code so I'm not sure about that, but you can do that easily using .tostring function

Comment: Instead of using an intent would this code also work if I implemented the layout as a fragment?

Comment: of course, that will work just fine. Did you just try doing this? But I recommend you to check pages suggested by Andres. Best of luck

Comment: Sorry, but you have to use +"" instead of .toString() to primitive datatypes, to both boolean and integer..