# Android -> ListView - How to style 2 textviews to one line?

Tags: android, listview

i have a list item and i would like to style 2 (or more) text views in one line.

```
------------------------------------------------
|                                              |    
| TEXT_VIEW_1: FOO    TEXT_VIEW_2: BAR         |   
|                                              | 
|                                              |
------------------------------------------------
```

How to do it most simple and effective?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: It's all explained in this thread. You just need to modify XML that textviews are side by side and you are done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832335/android-custom-row-item-for-listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your list item layout as below...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="FOO" />

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="BAR" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to have more than 2 `TextView` then just add `android:layout_weight="1"` attribute to them. If all `TextView` contains `android:layout_weight="1"` then this attribute will distribute layout width equally to all `Textviews`.

Comment: by setting weight may effect with the content of the textview. consider one as long text and the other a small it may affect the view.

Comment: If `android:layout_weight="1"` is set to all `TextView` then long will not cause any problem.

Comment: it will effect try to fill the first textview with large text and the second with small. and one thing ,its a listview so we need to show the list in an aligned manner.

Comment: At first, the parent `LinearLayout` will collect all the `weight` then it will divide its `width` with the sum of `weight`  and then divided result will set to all `TextViews` as `layout_width`.

Answer (score 0):

Use orientation of LinearLayout as Horizontal:

and provide weights:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Text1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Text2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Text3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code for list item.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightsum="2" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="FOO" />

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="BAR" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And make both textview singleLine true.