# how to create imageview as checkbox in android listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

i want to create a List View in android studio and use Imageview or Imagebutton as Checkbox plz help me,

if user clicked on the image, item show as checked
,
infact i want use a imageview as check box

like this picture

[image]

Comment: What have you tried this far? It's commonly expected that questions in StackOverflow show some effort in terms of actual code. So, maybe try some programming on your own, and then ask specific questions concerning parts you have trouble with. Consider putting aside a few minutes to take a look at [some guidelines about asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) too.

Answer (score 1):

as answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15832564/2646182), you need to create customlistAdapter:

so you can design your own list layout in xml file and put it in layout folder then use it as a listview layout.
if its true anser, please duplicate the question with the link anser