# Android Studio ListView, limit the length of the lines

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView but some of the text items in the list go beyond the width limit which word wraps. Normally this is fine; however, i'd like to show as many lines as possible in the ListView so is there a way to clip or limit to a certain character length and put the ellipsis at the end

example:
This is a really long line of text that will wrap around

to this
This is a really long line...

I've seen a few xml lines for a TextView

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

which works for a TetView but not seeing anything for a ListView to do that (did try using those xml options but it didn't work)

the closest I found was the following

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

which didn't work, unless it's a bug in Android Studio or maybe the emulator?

I'm using the latest updated version on a Windows 10 machine

```
Android Studio 2.1.3
Build #AI-143.3101438
jdk1.8.0_91
```

Thank you

EDIT
XML code for the activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.danield.notes.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textFilterEnabled="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What kind of layout are you using in your list items? Also could you provide more code please.

Comment: Try changing that to a linear layout, or a frame layout. Also your list item itself doesn't have it's own layout or does it?

Comment: no the ListView doesn't have a layout. Trying the other two types had no effect

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clean and rebulid the project ?

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the full XML ?

Comment: For this you better use the Custom Adapter example here : http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

Comment: In the custom list_item use the ellipseline and maxline in textview this is the proper way .

Comment: Like example <TextViewandroid:id="@+id/secondLineTextView"android:layout_width="wrap_content"android:layout_height="wrap_content"android:maxLines="1"android:maxLength="10"android:ellipsize="end"/>

Comment: sorry, i'm relatively new to Android Studio, do you have an example?

Comment: Here is the example to custom Adapter :  http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link [Android custom Row Item for ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832335/android-custom-row-item-for-listview)!

Create a custom layout for you listview item and add these params to your TextView:

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Hope this helps :)