# Format database results as comma separated

Tags: android, database

Following the tutorial from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832335/android-custom-row-item-for-listview) on Stackoverflow. After querying the database, I have records in variable `results`. How do I format the results so that it can be a array. Below is an example:

```
lvActivityCategory.setAdapter(new categoryCursorAdaptor(this, new String[] { "data1", "data2" }));
```

This is the code that am currently working with:

```
        List<String> arrayCatNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY name ASC";
        Cursor results = myDB.rawQuery(query, null);
        while(results.moveToNext()){
            String catName = results.getString(results.getColumnIndex("name"));
            arrayCatNames.add(catName);
        }
        android.text.TextUtils.join(",", arrayCatNames);
        lvActivityCategory = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvActivityCategory);
        lvActivityCategory.setAdapter(new categoryCursorAdaptor(this, new String[] { arrayCatNames })); //arrayCatNames should be e.g. "item 1", "item 2", "item 3"
```

Comment: Are you trying to convert ArrayList arrayCatNames to an Array ?

Comment: @HtmlTosin Yes that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, do this below, after your while loop

```
String[] catNamesArr = new String[arrayCatNames.size()];
catNamesArr = arrayCatNames.toArray(catNamesArr);
```

You can learn more reading this question: [Convert ArrayList<String> to String[] array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374311/convert-arrayliststring-to-string-array)