# Divider not working for ListView in Android studio

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I am trying to add spacing to my list items in ListView. I have tried using divider and dividerHeight but this doesn't seem to work. Please what could be wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_export_logistics"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.orume.export.ExportLogisticsActivity">


<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></include>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:background="#fff"></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**divider.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line" >

<stroke
    android:width="20dp"
    android:color="#dd0d0d" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Write `android:divider="@drawable/divider"`instead of `android:divider="@null"`

Comment: @WhiteHox: Check-> android:divider="@null". Add color to it.!!

Comment: Write android:divider="@layout/divider"

Answer (score 1):

you don't set your divider to your `ListView`.
`android:divider="@null"` `@null` here means that you set the divider to empty. Now you have a drawable `divider.xml`, and you need to tell Android that you want it to be used as a divider.

If your `divider.xml` is placed under `drawable` directory, then use `android:divider="@drawable/divider"`

Comment: If you can just comment out your answer, Do not post it as 'Answer'. Just comment it!!

Comment: @AndiGeeky, why? it **is** an answer, not a comment!

Comment: @AndiGeeky, also my **answer** was giwen **before**  your and Ankita Shah comment

Comment: Any answer should be descriptive and well contended!!

Comment: @AndiGeeky, ok, and why you think that my answer lacks it?

Comment: @AndiGeeky, you see - people think that my answer is OK by upvoting it back after your and smbd's else downvote.

Comment: @All  Keep calm .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, ok, can you maybe say what is wrong with my answer by your opinion?

Comment: @AndiGeeky, completely disagree with you, Vlad's answer is short but fully understandable and per my opinion the right one. Doesn't matter if someone else has already answered in the same manner, maybe he will edit his answer later with adding some additional info. The point here is that you had only commented, but he had given an answer, but nevertheless it doesn't mean that someone is doing good or bad, your aim should be helping people. That's my thought.

Comment: @YuriiTsap, one more point is that my answer was posted 2 seconds before anybody commented and posted other answer. It was the **first one**.

Comment: @VladMatvienko avoid the topic. keep your good works . Frankly speaking i avoid quarrel . Make earth pollution free

Comment: the drawable didn't work either that's why i used null. But I have gotten a solution. tHANKS. @AndiGeeky

Comment: @WhiteHox: Welcome! Can you post your solution here and how you solved it?

Comment: @WhiteHox, just ask Vlad to attach a valid drawable example - and your issue will be fixed. This answer should be accepted as correct.

Comment: I am just suggesting. If Anyone don't feel same, they have all rights to speak up! Appreciate response!

Comment: @AndiGeeky, I've made just another suggestion, but it wasn't so aggressive as yours :) Nevertheless, thanks for discussion.

Comment: Guess my question wasn't explicit enough. I tried drawable and null but neither worked for my desired spacing between list items but i have posted the solution that worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Found a way out. I ended up add `android:layout_marginBottom` to the texView that defines my ListView and it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: how does it set the divider to the drawable, you wanted?

Comment: The aim was to add spacing between the list items using the divider set to drawable. But that didn't work for what i wanted so i added marginBottom to the TextView for my ListView. @VladMatvienko

Comment: well, that is not a *correct* solution as for me. I'd suggest you to use `dividerHeight`, and set `divider` to the transparent color. With your solution it will add etra space even after the last list item

Comment: Tried all that before coming to SO. Am aware of the spacing after the list item. I used this beacuse the activity contains only ListView. Maybe i should add that to my solution. Anyways thanks for your help @VladMatvienko

Answer (score -1):

Create a custom view for your list items and give top and bottom padding or other space adjustments inside that custom item layout to bring space for list items. An eg link is below 
[Android custom Row Item for ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832335/android-custom-row-item-for-listview)

Also another note is giving divider height might not work well.

Answer (score -2):

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:background="#fff"></ListView>
```

replace this listview with yours..