# How to add button on each row in ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to implement button on each row in ListView, but I saw many topics and I don't succeeded to add code to mine. Here is my MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> items;
private ImageButton formButton;
private ListView lvMain;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    commonFunction();
}

public void commonFunction() {
    lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    readItems();
    itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            items);
    lvMain.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
    formButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
    formButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setLayoutActivity();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is my activity_main.xml :

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lvMain"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnPlus" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_plus_foreground" />
```

Does someone any idea how to do ?

Comment: Create a separate XML for each type of row you want in your ListView, then create the row from that XML layout file in your ListAdapter. You need a custom adapter for custom rows.

Comment: you need custom adapter with a custom xml for row. you cannot do it with new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            items);

Comment: First of all I suggest you to use `RecyclerView` :) Create a custom adapter and `@Override getItemViewType()` then you will handle each view based on the returned it ;) I can come up with an example if you decide to go for this implementation

Comment: Create h custom Listview with button, go with this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832335/android-custom-row-item-for-listview

Comment: you have to use custom adapter with custom row_item layout

Answer (score 1):

Create custom adapter with custom row layout file and add button on that row file and bind it to List/Recycler view. So it will inflate in all row.

Add below code in row_list.xml file.

```
<ImageButton
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="65dp"
android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_plus_foreground" />
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;


/*************  CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
public CustomAdapter(ArrayList d) {

    /********** Take passed values **********/
    data = d;

    /***********  Layout inflater to call external xml layout () ***********/
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

/******** What is the size of Passed Arraylist Size ************/
public int getCount() {

    if (data.size() <= 0)
        return 1;
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

/********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
public static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageButton button;

}

/****** Depends upon data size called for each row , Create each ListView row *****/
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list, null);

        /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.button = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);

        /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Button click
        }
    });
    return vi;
}}
```

Hope it will solve problem.

Happy coding!!

Comment: I think there is a problem with <activity.getSystemService>, the IDE doesn't recognize <activity> and if I add all this code, where must I initialize CustomAdapter in my code ? Thanks again for help.

Answer (score 1):

Crate custom adapter and bind it with the ListView.
Inflate custom layout for each row in the adapter.
You can put your button in the custom layout file.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Context context;

private int singleRowLayoutId;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int singleRowLayoutId, String []titles, String []desc, int []images ) {
    super(context, singleRowLayoutId,titles);
    this.context=context;
    this.singleRowLayoutId=singleRowLayoutId; //custom row layout for list view item
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    View row=convertView;
    CustomViewHolder holder=null;
    if(row==null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //view object of single row of list view
        row = inflater.inflate(singleRowLayoutId, parent, false);
        //by using holder, we make sure that findViewById() is not called every time.
        holder=new CustomViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder=(CustomViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    return row;
}

private class CustomViewHolder {
    private ImageButton mbtn;

    CustomViewHolder(View view)
    {
        mbtn=(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn);

        mbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //handle button click here
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: Used ViewHolder to improve performance of ListView so that findViewById() is only called first time.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you need - create a separate layout for the rows in the list view. Then create a custom adapter, where you are adding this layout as row layout and then set this adapter to your list view. Here are the details with examples:

[Android custom Row Item for ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832335/android-custom-row-item-for-listview)