# How to use separator in listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, view, android-listview

I have a listview which have json data. Data is coming with a flag like 0, 1, 2. I want to apply separator in listview based on the flag value. Like if the data have `flag=0` then all respective data must be shown in listview under `flag=0` separator. Then other separator must have all the values of `flag=1`.

Comment: Try expandable listview

Comment: You need multi section listview. http://andytsui.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/tutorial-displaying-multiple-lists-in-one-single-listview-with-android-binding/

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you basically want some headers, where you will display `flag=0` or `flag=1` or other titles. You can have more types of views in your adapter, so some of them can be headers and other contents, take a look at this [Android ListView headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590627/android-listview-headers)