# How to have sections in navigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am trying to make a navigationDrawer in Android v4.0+ to be exactly like in [this example](http://developer.android.com/design/media/navigation_drawer_titles_icons.png)  in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) of android.

However I do not find any documentation how to achieve this. All I can find is telling me to extend the ListView, but that just sounds weird as it looks like the native android classes should have this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for "ListView header items". One way to achieve such layout is to let your (custom) adapter know that the items at specific positions (or some other criteria) have to be displayed with different layout and populate a different view for those items in it's [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method.

Comment: do you have an example of how this could be achieved? If i understand correctly, i should add Custom class objects from which properties adapter would know which View it has to return?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590627/android-listview-headers It looks like it's well explained. If you find it not suitable, search for "android listview header" and see what other solutions might exist