# Can't setAdapter() inside a Dialog pop up Android?

Tags: java, android, dialog

I came across a really frustrating problem. I have a button with an onClick event  that should display a dialog pop up with a ExpandableListView inside of it.

This is the code:

```
public class Home extends Activity {

List<String> groupList;
List<String> childList;
Map<String, List<String>> laptopCollection;
ExpandableListView expListView; 

private Context thisContext = this; 

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    createGroupList();

    createCollection();


    Intent myDataIntent = this.getIntent();
    // getting the municipality name, the year and the versed money from the prev. intent
    this.municipalityName = myDataIntent.getStringExtra(TAG_COMUNE);
    this.year = myDataIntent.getStringExtra(TAG_ANNO);
    this.versedMoney = myDataIntent.getStringExtra(TAG_VERSED_MONEY);


    Button infoListButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.infoButton);

    infoListButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // custom dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(thisContext);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.institutional_info_custom_list);
            dialog.setTitle("Info");

            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) thisContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = li.inflate(R.layout.institutional_info_custom_list, null, false);
            dialog.setContentView(v);

            expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                 final ExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(
                        Home.this, groupList, laptopCollection);
            /// THE APP CRASHES HERE
            expListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter);

            // getting the window manager and changing the dialog position
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
            params.y = 80;
            dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
            // dialog width and height.
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);         

            // set the custom dialog components

            dialog.show();
          }
    });
}


 private void createGroupList() {
        groupList = new ArrayList<String>();
        groupList.add("HP");
        groupList.add("Dell");
        groupList.add("Lenovo");
        groupList.add("Sony");
        groupList.add("HCL");
        groupList.add("Samsung");
    }

    private void createCollection() {
        // preparing laptops collection(child)
        String[] hpModels = { "HP Pavilion G6-2014TX", "ProBook HP 4540",
                "HP Envy 4-1025TX" };
        String[] hclModels = { "HCL S2101", "HCL L2102", "HCL V2002" };
        String[] lenovoModels = { "IdeaPad Z Series", "Essential G Series",
                "ThinkPad X Series", "Ideapad Z Series" };
        String[] sonyModels = { "VAIO E Series", "VAIO Z Series",
                "VAIO S Series", "VAIO YB Series" };
        String[] dellModels = { "Inspiron", "Vostro", "XPS" };
        String[] samsungModels = { "NP Series", "Series 5", "SF Series" };

        laptopCollection = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

        for (String laptop : groupList) {
            if (laptop.equals("HP")) {
                loadChild(hpModels);
            } else if (laptop.equals("Dell"))
                loadChild(dellModels);
            else if (laptop.equals("Sony"))
                loadChild(sonyModels);
            else if (laptop.equals("HCL"))
                loadChild(hclModels);
            else if (laptop.equals("Samsung"))
                loadChild(samsungModels);
            else
                loadChild(lenovoModels);

            laptopCollection.put(laptop, childList);
        }
    }

    private void loadChild(String[] laptopModels) {
        childList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String model : laptopModels)
            childList.add(model);
    }


}
```

Here is the ExpandableListAdapter class:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Activity context;
private Map<String, List<String>> laptopCollections;
private List<String> laptops;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Activity context, List<String> laptops,
        Map<String, List<String>> laptopCollections) {
    this.context = context;
    this.laptopCollections = laptopCollections;
    this.laptops = laptops;
}

public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return laptopCollections.get(laptops.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String laptop = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.institutional_rowlist_detail, null);
    }

    TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.institutional_detail_name);

    item.setText(laptop);
    return convertView;
}

public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return laptopCollections.get(laptops.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return laptops.get(groupPosition);
}

public int getGroupCount() {
    return laptops.size();
}

public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String laptopName = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.institutional_rowlist_master,
                null);
    }
    TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.institutional_detail_name);
    item.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    item.setText(laptopName);
    return convertView;
}

public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

And here are the 4 .xml files I am using (the first is the Home activity XML, called activity_home.xml, which has the button, the second is the one with the ExpandableListView, the third is the one with the group entry Text View, and the last is the detail one):

1) activity_home.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/investStatButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="@string/investStatButton" />

   </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

2) institutional_info_custom_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <ExpandableListView
       android:id="@android:id/list"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

</ExpandableListView>
```

3) institutional_rowlist_master.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/institutional_master_name"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:gravity="left"
android:paddingLeft="32dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:textAlignment="textEnd"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

4) institutional_rowlist_detail.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="40dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/institutional_detail_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/institutional_detail_value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I click on the button the app crashes and I get a Java Null Pointer exception at the  expListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter); line in the Home activity.

Please help me cause it is all day I am surfing the net in search for some clues... I do not know what to do.

Thanks!

EDIT: this is the image

[image]

EDIT: thank you codeMagic, I made it: 
[image]

Now I would like to customize the Info Title bar, i.e. add a button with an onclick event to dismiss() the dialog and some text views. Is it possible??? How can I do that?

Comment: Now that I can show the expandablelist, is there a way to show the details in that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, it is looking for the `ExpandableListView` inside of `activity_home.xml` when it should be looking in the `layout` that you inflate for your `Dialog`. Change it to

```
expListView = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

**Edit**

you are using `"@android:id/list"` for the `id` of your `ListView`. This should be used if your `Activity` `extends ListActivity` otherwise you should give it your own `id` and use that to access it in `findViewById()`. Either way, you need to be looking in the correct `layout` file as I have originally noted in my answer.

Comment: Is the declaration of this id correct that way? Will @android:id/list even add the id to the ressources?

Comment: @Ascorbin it doesn't need to add it to the `resources` because it's an Android `resource` so it is already there

Comment: Don't really get it, he's inflating his own layout from institutional_info_custom_list.xml there, how does his own ListView already have an id within the android resources?

Comment: @Ascorbin Ah, you are right, the OP isn't extending `ListActivity`. I guess I was just assuming without paying attention. I will update my answer. Thanks

Comment: @codeMagic Man you did it!!! Thank you Thank you so much I was getting mad of trying ot understand what was going on. Now it works perfectly!  I would like to ask only one more thing: at the moment the dialog displays an expandable list with a group and the details displayed when I click on the group textView. Is there a way to display both the Group and the proper details without having to click on the group textView? I edit my question and attach an image so it can be clearer.

Comment: @user3019105 if you want just headers and don't need it to be expandable, which I think is what you are saying, [see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590627/android-listview-headers/13634801#13634801)

Comment: Thank you so much for the post! I made it. I have only the last a last question, in the EDIT I posted my result image. If you see the dialog title has an "Info" title I have set with .setTitle("Info"). Is there a way to add textViews and a Button on which I can bind an event in order to .dismiss() the dialog on the dialog title bar? And anyway, is it possible to customize the dialog bar? I mean, padding, margin, etc??? Thanks!

Comment: You would probably want to either want to create a class which `extends Dialog` and you could do it all in there. Or it may be easier to just make this a separate `Activity` and give it a `Dialog Theme` in your `manifest.xml` then you can just create the `View`s you need. I do this in some cases to have `Button`s etc... and get the full functionality of an `Activity` while looking like a `Dialog`.