# android disable custom header listview

Tags: android, listview

I am following compass listview adapter. from this thread

[Android ListView headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590627/android-listview-headers/24405478?noredirect=1#comment37753749_24405478)

The problem is that the headers are clickable. how can I disable it.

If the position was fixed was easy but they aren't fixed.

I tried this but no luck :(

```
if (convertView == null) {
    view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.listasheader, null);
   view.setClickable(false);
    // Do some initialization
} else {
    view = convertView;
    view.setClickable(false);

    public interface Item {
        public int getViewType();
        public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView);
    }
```

here is compass code (from the thread):

```
public class TwoTextArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public enum RowType {
        LIST_ITEM, HEADER_ITEM
    }

    public TwoTextArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
        super(context, 0, items);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return RowType.values().length;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return getItem(position).getViewType();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getItem(position).getView(mInflater, convertView);
    }
}
```

Then we have classes the implement `Item` and inflate the correct layouts.  In your case you'll have something like a `Header` class and a `ListItem` class.

```
   public class Header implements Item {
    private final String         name;

    public Header(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewType() {
        return RowType.HEADER_ITEM.ordinal();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView) {
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
            // Do some initialization
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.separator);
        text.setText(name);

        return view;
    }

}
```

And then the `ListItem` class

```
    public class ListItem implements Item {
    private final String         str1;
    private final String         str2;

    public ListItem(String text1, String text2) {
        this.str1 = text1;
        this.str2 = text2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewType() {
        return RowType.LIST_ITEM.ordinal();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView) {
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, null);
            // Do some initialization
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_content1);
        TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_content2);
        text1.setText(str1);
        text2.setText(str2);

        return view;
    }

}
```

And a simple `Activity` to display it

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        items.add(new Header("Header 1"));
        items.add(new ListItem("Text 1", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new ListItem("Text 2", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new ListItem("Text 3", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new ListItem("Text 4", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new Header("Header 2"));
        items.add(new ListItem("Text 5", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new ListItem("Text 6", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new ListItem("Text 7", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new ListItem("Text 8", "Rabble rabble"));

        TwoTextArrayAdapter adapter = new TwoTextArrayAdapter(this, items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Layout for `R.layout.header`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:text="Header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#757678"
        android:textColor="#f5c227" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout for `R.layout.my_list_item`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_content1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:paddingBottom="1dip"
        android:paddingTop="1dip"
        android:text="sample"
        android:textColor="#ff7f1d"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_content2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:linksClickable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:paddingBottom="1dip"
        android:paddingTop="1dip"
        android:text="sample"
        android:textColor="#6d6d6d"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout for `R.layout.activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this line in `getView()` before this `return view;`

```
@Override
public View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView) {


    .....



    text1.setOnClickListener(null);
    return view;
}
```