# Is something wrong with my Adapter notifyDataSetChanged()?

Tags: android, listview, notifydatasetchanged, sectionheader

I'm trying to use the listview with sectionheaders as mentioned here:
[Android ListView headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590627/android-listview-headers)

The values are populated dynamically as shown below:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult called");
    if((requestCode == 1)&&(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)){
        if(data!= null){
            AddedTask=data.getStringExtra("NewTask");
            CategoryName=data.getStringExtra("CategoryItem");
            TaskTime=data.getStringExtra("TaskTime");
            List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
                items.add(new Header(CategoryName));
                items.add(new ListItem(AddedTask, TaskTime));
                TwoTextArrayAdapter adapter = new TwoTextArrayAdapter(getActivity(), items);
                listViewData.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

My Problem is when I add the values first time its adding perfect. But when I get the values second time the values are simply updating with the previous values and not showing me the first added values.

Comment: well of course. `items` contains what you are returning from the other activity, and nothing more. You are also instantiating a new `TwoTextArrayAdapter` and, calling `setAdapter`, you are replacing the old one. `notifyDataSetChanged` does nothing in this case, but it is not its fault

Comment: @Blacbelt- Ah silly! I havent gone through the silly mistake I have done. Got working now..but the problem is each time I addthe Item it dosent check of the header is same or not and add the new list to the existing header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add some items in the second time, they will replace with the first one, because you declare a new "items" every time. 
You should declare "items" as a public variable outside the onActivityResult function. 
You can do something like this:

```
List<Item> items;
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult called");
if((requestCode == 1)&&(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)){
    if(data!= null){
        AddedTask=data.getStringExtra("NewTask");
        CategoryName=data.getStringExtra("CategoryItem");
        TaskTime=data.getStringExtra("TaskTime");
        if (items == null)
            items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        items.add(new Header(CategoryName));
            items.add(new ListItem(AddedTask, TaskTime));
            TwoTextArrayAdapter adapter = new TwoTextArrayAdapter(getActivity(), items);
            listViewData.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line has issue

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

Every time it creates a new `List` and the previous values are cleared

Declare it outside a method