# Listview with child and parent views from a TreeMap<String,ArrayList<String>>

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I guess my situation should be quite common and it should have a simple solution (of which I'm not aware). Indeed, I want to use a `TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` in my `Adapter` to show the countries in a `ListView`. I have created this list (shown in the following picture) without using `ListView` but it is quite inefficient.

My question:

Does `ListView` suit this task?
yes: How should I define the adapter?
No: What else can I use which is as efficient as the `ListView`?

BTW, my TreeMap is like This: ("C", {"Country1","Country2",...})

[image]

As you can see in the above image I want to use different dividers (the logic is obvious).

Comment: But seems like the dividers are same?

Comment: @FireSun If you notice, at the end of each group (for example countries which their names begin with B) the divider's width is full (the whole) screen.

Comment: the easiest way is to use SectionIndexer ...  `final int section = getSectionForPosition(position);
        if (position == getPositionForSection(section)) {
            final TextView text = (TextView) ret.findViewById(R.id.section);
            text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            text.setText((String)getSections()[section]);
        }
        else
        {
            ret.findViewById(R.id.section).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }` TextView with R.id.section is your section

Comment: @Selvin Thank you. It seams to be exactly the case. I found this source easily with the keyword you provide: http://androidopentutorials.com/android-listview-fastscroll/

Comment: :) http://selvin.pl/LooserSample.zip <=(name of project is historical, do not take to yourself) example usage (the code from comment is inside getView() - and could be better it just a prove of concept) and results => https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B61_ocdRW25TNWpaTURoemhPczA  unfortunately(for you) it using ContentProvider and database :) (so CursorAdapter instead ArrayAdapter)

Comment: @Selvin :) Thank you very much. I'll do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood you want to use `ListView` with headers: `'A', 'B', 'C'` etc. In that case you can rely to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590627/android-listview-headers)

If you don't need headers, then you can feed your ListView with the values() of your TreeMap, maybe you'd like some ordering before passing it to the `ListView`. However I don't see why wouldn't you want headers if you have sorted collections by letters :)

So, for header views, you need to define you `ListView`'s adapter in a specific way.

I must also mention, that there's a `View` with better performance overall than `ListView`, which is called [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html), I suggest to have a check on that! It also has the option to add headers for the list items.

**EDIT:** I couldn't see the attached image, thus some more possibilities:

I'd suggest to use normal ListView/RecyclerView with a special `Adapter`, not a normal string one. Create a class which contains a String and a boolean, and transform your map to a list of these objects. 
Something like this:

```
public class ListItem{
    String name;
    String category;
    boolean isHeader;
    [...]
}
```

If the object is a first item, set the boolean true. In the list adapter you can check the item's Boolean, and create the actual item's view according to it, in your `Adapter`'s `getView()` method.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the other option too. Also, I should mention that I put the key besides the first child, not above it.

Comment: I will try to see whether I can use the first link first

Comment: Oh sorry I couldn't load the image on my mobile, now I see it.

Comment: Did it affect your answer?

Comment: I'd suggest to use normal ListView/RecyclerView with special adapter, not a normal string one. Create a class which contains a String and a Boolean, and transform your map to a list of these objects. If the object is a first item, set the Boolean true. In the list adapter you can check the item's Boolean, and create the actual item view according to it.

Comment: I know this solution, but this is something else. Do you think this is the best solution and I cannot pass a map to my adapter?

Comment: Also you can set the letter to it, but as long as the list of the new class's objects are ordered by the names, you should get a satisfying result

Comment: So far I guess this is the best plausible solution, cause It seems using a map is not that much straightforward, is it?

Comment: It can be used in the adapter, but maybe it's not very good for performance.

Comment: I guess using this approach (+1) in inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

I think `ListView` is suitable to do this,but `RecyclerView` will do better, just depends on how we custom the adapter for it.
And I think `TreeMap` will be slower and waste much memory,that is,it can make it but too waste.Simply you can use `HashMap` instead,more simplier,you can use `SparseMap<List<String>>` instead,the key is `0-25` and value is city list,this will use less memory.

Comment: Thanks. Can I use a Map as the adapter? BTW, I use ThreeMap to get the keys in a sorted fashion. Filling it takes 1 milli-seconds.

Comment: you can use the map as data source for adapter,and if you use `SparseMap` you can also get the sorted fashion,for example if you want to take value from starts with `A` to starts with `Z`,you just call `map.get(0-25)`.

Comment: Great. But still I don't know how to use the map as data source. I have seen examples of map <string, string> as the source but not any example with map<string, list> as the data source.

Comment: use this structor just for data management and use less memory,if you have  achieve your goal by `TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`,that will be similar with it.just take list values from `String` like `A` to from `int` like `0`.

Comment: Well, indeed you mentioned another issue (+1). My problem (using a map as the data source of the adapter) still exists.

Comment: Will your city data change when app running?

Comment: No. But I want to use this solution in another case wherein either the keys (parents, a-z e.g.) and the values (children, countries) may change.