# Android add a view at the beginning of a listview

Tags: android, listview, view, inflate

I have a listview with a base adapter. I have an inflater which gives the style for each item of my list, but the thing I want to do is to add a view at the beginning of the listview with a different inflated layout.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  There's two ways of doing it.  The first is to add a listview header. The second is to add an item to your adapter that holds the first place in the list, and map it as if it was an item.

Comment: Would you be so kind to write an example?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of
[Android ListView headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590627/android-listview-headers)

This might also help.
http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android