# I want to create a listview like in play store installed apps fragment

Tags: android, listview

I want to create a list view which shows some detail (batch name in my case) on the top of some listview items like this screenshot of [play store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5aef.png). Here it shows downloading on top of a few items and updates or installed on others. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use CardView

Comment: Try Using ListView Header its simple [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590627/android-listview-headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590627/android-listview-headers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your official reference for creating `RecyclerView`:

[Creating Lists and Cards](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Also, you may follow this:

[Using lists and grids in Android with RecylerView - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html)

You will exactly get the most of building `RecyclerView` considering design patterns

Here is an example of creating `RecyclerView` with **header**:

```
    public class HeaderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    String[] data;

    public HeaderAdapter(String[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder
            return new VHItem(null);
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder
            return new VHHeader(null);
        }

        throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof VHItem) {
            String dataItem = getItem(position);
            //cast holder to VHItem and set data
        } else if (holder instanceof VHHeader) {
            //cast holder to VHHeader and set data for header.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.length + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionHeader(position))
            return TYPE_HEADER;

        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }

    private String getItem(int position) {
        return data[position - 1];
    }

    class VHItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;

        public VHItem(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    class VHHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        Button button;

        public VHHeader(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will I be able to add description at the top dynamically? @blueware

Comment: Yes, I will edit my answer to include an example of how to do this

Comment: How to notify the adapter about header or normal item

Comment: You can use the `getItemViewType` to determine which to notify the adapter about

Comment: And what if I want to create multiple headers (like in the image in description)

Comment: You can use a `RecyclerView` inside your header item and push multiple items to it to show downaloding

Answer (score 1):

You can use CardView - Design library.

add library in app level Gradle-

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.+'
```

here is guide of card view

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html

Comment: I shall try this one too.

Comment: I hope it's helpful for make cardview design. It's works on everywhere. like listview, gridview, layout etc.